# Write Conflict Error with SharePoint Linked Tables in Access 2010

Tags: 2013, microsoft-access

Using Access 2010 and SharePoint 2013. I linked Share Point 2013 list with Access 2010, this was working fine but started seeing conflict error this morning. It works fine after I refresh the list, but after a few moments it throws error for every change in the list. I tried unchecking Cache option in Access but that didn't help.

Comment: I was under the impression that huge workflow history list(500,000 items) might be causing this issue but i deleted the history list. Users are still seeing the same issue...any suggestions please?

Comment: I believe the reason for this error in Access is probably because of calculated column or workflow that is triggered after every row is modified and users are doing mass updates to the list. To explain in detail, if a user is modifying one single column for 30 rows, calculated columns are re-calculating and workflows are triggered even though no actions are performed. so mean while if user modifies another column in same rows, Access is throwing write-conflict error. Isn't Access an alternate option for SharePoint's List view threshold limit? Any ideas or suggestions or help is appreciated.